# Maven duplicate class with generated sources when using -f option

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I try to build a Maven project with classes generated from `jaxb2-maven-plugin`.

Consider the following minimal pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>test</packageName>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/resources/schema.xsd</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this minimal schema in `src/main/resources/schema.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:maxVersion="1.1" vc:minVersion="1.0" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

When invoking `mvn clean compile`, the project is built as expected. But when I specify the file using a path containing `..`, the following error occurs. When using a (relative or absolute) path *without* `..`, everything is fine.

```
C:\dev\test>mvn -f ..\test\pom.xml clean compile

[...]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/dev/test/target/generated-sources/jaxb/test/ObjectFactory.java:[32,8] duplicate class: test.ObjectFactory
```

How can I get rid of this error and build my project using `mvn -f <some path containing "..">`?

Comment: First why are you calling maven like that? Is this a multi module build? Why not changing into the correct directory and simply call Maven like `mvn clean compile`?

Comment: @khmarbaise I invoke Maven in a script - and since there are several other relative paths in that script, I don't want to change the location. Meanwhile, I figured out, that I can use an absolute path (without ..) and everything works as expected. But nontheless I'm curious why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For me (on macOS), the issue goes away when I don't have a "." component in my path:

```
maven compile -f ./blah/blah   # <-- "duplicate class" errors
maven compile -f blah/blah     # <-- works fine
```

Ugly workaround: Try using an absolute path?

(Seems like a path normalization bug in Maven or maven-compiler-plugin.)